# disable woocommerce product image flipping on mobile view

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on my WordPress website based on woocommerce there is an flipping effect on products images.

I just want to disable flipping effect for mobile view as I am not using any plugin for this effect(its a default option in my theme .)

The site is  [here](http://jetronics.ae/)